# How to Reduce Wallet Prompts for Enhanced User Experience in a Blockchain Gaming dApp?

Tags: metamask, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

I am developing a gaming dApp on the Ethereum network and aim to optimize the user experience, particularly in interactions with the blockchain. A major challenge is the frequent Metamask prompts users encounter when performing blockchain-related actions. I understand that consistent transaction confirmations can interrupt gameplay and potentially decrease user engagement.

What are the recommended strategies and technologies to reduce these prompts? Are there innovative solutions or best practices specific to gaming dApps that can make player-blockchain interactions more fluid?

Answer (score 2):

To streamline the user experience in a blockchain-based gaming dApp, consider the following strategies:

#### 1. Batch Transactions:

Batching allows you to group multiple actions into a single transaction. This can significantly reduce the frequency of Metamask prompts as players can make multiple decisions and then confirm them all at once.

Benefits:

- **User Experience**: Players engage in uninterrupted gameplay, performing several in-game actions before needing to confirm a single transaction.
- **Gas Efficiency**: Batching can sometimes save on gas fees, as fewer individual transaction overheads are needed.

#### 2. Meta-Transactions:

Meta-transactions capture the essence of user intent without immediately transacting on the blockchain. Instead of a user paying gas for each interaction, meta-transactions enable another party (like a relayer) to sponsor and broadcast these transactions.

Mechanisms:

**Gas Station Network (GSN)**: This decentralized solution allows dApps to subsidize transaction costs, offering a seamless experience to users. Users sign a message (their "intent"), and a relayer in the GSN processes the transaction on their behalf.

**ERC-4337 Account Abstraction with Smart Contract Accounts**: This recent standard offers a way to represent user operations without immediate blockchain transactions. If your users smart accounts supports [session keys](https://mirror.xyz/matchboxdao.eth/VXOvLKIvfXHP-cusKHw55zqlHpvvWwzh_fqm6j48Yek) then you can use this to "automatically sign" transactions for a specific period. You can also take a look at [this article by MetaMask](https://metamask.io/news/latest/account-abstraction-past-present-future/) for a comprehensive idea of all the features that are enabled by smart contract accounts.

Benefits:

- **Speed & UX**: Users only sign a message indicating their intent, which is typically faster than signing an entire transaction. This is because, for transactions, wallets often need to make preliminary calls to estimate gas cost and get the gas price.
- **Gas Abstraction**: Users don't need to own or understand ETH for gas payments, making the dApp more accessible, especially to newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to explore the best approaches to minimize or even eliminate the need for users to open Metamask repeatedly.

- Create an in-game hosted wallet that can be e.g. a web browser localStrorage based wallet
- The game code has direct access to the private key of this wallet
- The game code sign transactions using the private key programmatically
- Ask the users to deposits asset to this special wallet

Alternative

- Ask the user to deposit assets to a smart contract where the game server logic has a special role to perform some operations on these assets, similar to Uniswap, OpenSea and other DEXes

Comment: I wouldn't recommend dApps manage private keys directly in localStorage, it's much safe using trusted wallet providers such as Metamask.